Outdoor garage lights, front porch light, and foyer light and outlets don't work
I have limited electrical knowledge, so I'm hoping for some helpful ideas here.  My outdoor garage lights and front porch light are controlled by the same switch. The foyer light is controlled by a separate switch, but both switches are directly next to each other on the wall, contained within one cover. My lights began to work intermittently. One night they’d work fine, but the next night they wouldn’t. On the nights they didn’t work, I’d leave the switch on, and they’d sometimes randomly turn on in the middle of the night or the next day—only to stop working again later. All these lights are on the same circuit breaker.
I replaced the GFCI outlet by the front porch, but the issue persisted. Then, one day, when I turned on the foyer light, I saw it briefly light up before immediately turning off. Since that moment, none of the lights or outlets in the foyer or on the porch have worked—not even intermittently.
I checked the wiring for the light switches controlling the foyer and outdoor lights, as well as the foyer outlet. Everything appears normal. However, the new GFCI outlet I installed on the front porch no longer shows the green light indicating it has power, which it did when the lights were still working.
Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Are all of those lights on one circuit breaker?  Where did you see the "bit of light"?

Regrettably, more information is needed. For example, are they wired on the same circuit? Does current pass though a switch or outlet circuit that has "stab" connectors (a common source of loose connection)?

It looks like your recent edits, while improving formatting and readability, did not address the questions from Barry and Dr Moishe Pippik about whether all these failing devices are on one circuit breaker, or Dr Pippik's question about the "stab" connectors. As such, the question is still unanswerable. If you do not know how to get the answers to these questions, you'll probably need a local electrician to help.
